# android spinner value set

Tags: android, spinner

am having `activity` First here am sending values got in to Second `activity`.

in second `activity` contain `textview` and `spinner` . here `spinner` contains values as johncena ,Rock,undertaker....

so in `activity` am getting values as card2 and Rock which am passing to nextscreen through `intent`.so in next `activity` 
`cardNumber.setText(cardReceived);`  so here for `textview` we are giving like above for `spinner` how we have to do.

so when i navigate from first `activity` to nextactivity `spinner` value has to display as Rock.

but it shows default value johncena.

similarly if i get values as card 3 and undertaker then if i navigates to second `activity` then it has to display card3 and undertaker (for `spinner`).

but it shows card3 and johncena (default value)

```
Intent send =new Intent(First.this, Second.class);


send.putExtra("card",cardList.get(position));  

send.putExtra("name",nameList.get(position));

startActivity(edit);



String cardReceived = getIntent().getStringExtra("card");

cardNumber =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cardnumber); 

 cardNumber.setText(cardReceived);


String nameReceived = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

    System.out.println("name "+nameReceived);






Spinner NameDetail = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);    
        List list = new ArrayList();    

        list.add("Johncena");
        list.add("Rock");   
        list.add("UnderTaker");         


        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    cardDetail.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use:

```
// Set this integer to be between 0 and N-1, where the adapter has N entries
// 0 is the first you put in the adapter, N-1 the last
int selection = 2;

cardDetail.setSelection(selection);
```